# Automatic redirect to login page after a certain time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, ef-model-first

**I am using form authentication. My code in web.config is:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="5" />
</authentication>
```

**I've used [Authorize] at the head of the actions, that need authentication to access. As my configuration in web.config after five minutes an user is redirected to "../Home/Index" if he/she tries to access an action or load a page that is need authentication to access. Is there any way to do it automatically. I mean if the system is idle, like though no one is using the system after five minutes it will automatically redirect to "../Home/Index" page.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to add a `meta-refresh` tag to your Layout:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="310">
```

This will tell the browser to refresh the page every 5 minutes and 10 seconds. If the browser refreshes.. your timeout will kick in and redirect the user.